# The "try every possible sequence until you get it right" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, pseudocode

This is probably completely rudimentary, but I'm still not sure how to do it.

Suppose that I have a list `action` of functions/operators/what-have-you and an object `x`. For some stored value `y`, I want to check if it is possible to obtain `y` by applying the members of `action`, and return the shortest sequence of actions which takes `x` to `y`.

The easiest way to do this is to apply every possible sequence of actions to `x` in order, returning the first sequence to yield `y` (this will always be the shortest possible sequence).

I have a vague idea of how this might be done but I'm not clear on the specifcs - something like:

```
//Set the maximum number of steps (to prevent overflow)
n = whatever

//Algorithm

<<start>>

While i<n

  u = x
  sequence = []

  <<begin loop-like thing
    u = apply actions to u
    sequence = sequence.append(action.index(last action))
  end loop-like thing>>

  i = i + 1

  if u==y
    print sequence
  else
    <<return to start>>
```

(I'm using `<<stuff>>` as a placeholder for when I don't know what `stuff` is).

For a concrete example of application, consider `action` to be the list of legal twists of a Rubik's cube, and `x` to be the starting (scrambled) state, and `y` to be the solved state. This solves the Rubik's cube using the fewest possible steps and prints the solution.

You could also do this to solve mazes, but that would be silly, because there are much faster ways to solve mazes.

Comment: It is also possible to apply eg IDA* to the Rubik's Cube. Anyway the tricky-seeming part of the algorithm here is essentially base-converting the index of the sequence to base-k where k is the number of actions that you can do

Comment: What you're looking for is a [breadth-first-search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Depending on the details of the problem, a BFS can use a lot of memory before reaching a solution. One optimization is to recognize that a particular value `v` is reachable by multiple action sequences, and only keep one such sequence.